# How to change the name of a file as it is unzipped using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am unzipping a file in a folder, and saving in a new location. How do I rename that file immediately after unzipping it? After unzipping I will have a file like 1234_data.csv, how do I rewrite that as whatiwant.csv ?
I am aware I need to use a line such as `Name oldfile As NewFileName`

```
Sub Unzip1(str_FILENAME As String)  
    Dim oApp As Object  
    Dim Fname As Variant  
    Dim FnameTrunc As Variant  
    Dim FnameLength As Long 

    'Fname = str_FILENAME   'Commented out to show example file name
    Fname = "file.zip"  

FnameLength = Len(Fname)  
If Fname = False Then  
    'Do nothing  
    Else  

'Extract the files into the newly created folder  
          Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

oApp.NameSpace("C:\Users\Andrew\folder").CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Fname).Items  
DoEvents  
    End If  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  strPath = “c:\tempzips\”
  Fname = "new_file_name.zip"  

  If Len(Fname) Then  

    Name strPath + "original.zip" As strPath + Fname

  End If
```

Alternate based on comment

```
  Sub post_unzip(str_just_unzipped_filename As String, str_new_filename As String)

   str_path = "c:\thepathtothezips\"

   Name strpath + str_just_unzipped_filename As strpath + str_new_filename

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have multiple files in the folder, so your code would not overwrite the file correctly. It has to be performed on the newest file.